# replace special charaters in a string with escape sequence in shell programing

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have script file which replaces one word with other in files .

this is piece of code I use .now the problem I face is when Var1 and Var2 are path names .I m pretty new to shell scripting .I know i should put a escape sequence in front .since var1 and var2 are read from csv files i cant manually put escape sequences on them .is ther a way to detect  the special charaters before this command and replace them with escape sequence

$f is a file name

```
sed -i "s/$Var1/$Var2/g" "$f"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hy,

you can use a different character for separating statement :

```
sed "s%PATTERN%PATTERN%"
```

the first character seen by sed, after the command, will be used for separating your patterns.

In your example, this could be :

```
sed -i "s%$Var1%$Var2%g" "$f"
```

then `$Var1` and `$Var2` could hold any `/` but not `%`.
if you have to use the separator as pattern, you must escape it with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

You may quote the variables like this:

```
sed -i 's@'"${Var1}"'@'"${Var2}"'@g' "${f}"
```

also notice `/` is replaced with `@` because you mentioned path in the variables.

Comment: can this be used for normal word which dont have special charaters   or I shld use this only if the Var conatins '/' beacuse i may have either of it

Comment: **/** maybe replaced with **@**, **|**, **!**, etc. **freely** in *sed*.